# Optional Model Validation in Razor Page

Tags: validation, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, data-annotations

I have a "create account" form where I would like to collect data related to more than one model. While this is easy to accomplish, I am not able to figure out how to make the validation optional in the case where I would like to make something optional. Consider the example below.

Pseudo Code Form

```
Create Account
  Account Name
  …
Create Primary Contact
  Contact Name
  Contact Email
Create Contact Address (Optional)
  [ ] Skip Address
  Address Type
  Street
  City, State zip
```

In this example, I would like the validation to run on "create account", "create primary contact," and on the "create contact address" if the "Skip Address" is not selected. Please note that each of the sections above has its own model and own database repository.

Comment: Do you mean that when you create a user, you enter Name and Email, when you click Skip Address, the username and email you created will be matched with your current database, and a verification message will be prompted if it is repeated?

Comment: What I mean is in the example above I would like the fields Account Name, Contact Name, Contact Email required in all cases. The contact address would only trigger the validators if the the user choses not to skip address entry. In this example, area is coming from 3 different models with data annotations. My thought now is to add a property to the model that is bool for Skip, and to use the comparative data annotations.